# proof about limit of function

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Let $\lim_{x\to a}⁡〖f(x)〗=b$ and $\lim_{x\to b}⁡g(x)=c$.

Prove or disprove

$$\lim_{x→a}⁡〖g(f(x))〗=c$$

From what I understand about the transitive property, this should be true. However, I'm still doubt that answer, but I don't know any counter example to disprove it.

Comment: What transitive property are you referring to?

Comment: Are you expected to write "$\epsilon$-$\delta$" proofs?

Comment: @ Adam Saltz: the property I referred only work if $f(x)=b$ but I can't prove that.

Comment: @ Andre Nicolas, yes, I'm expect a proof with ϵ and δ because $a,b$ are cluster points.

Comment: What's the funny bracket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
Then there exists $\eta>0$ such that $|x-b|<\eta$ implies $|g(x)-c|<\epsilon$.
Likewise, for this $\eta>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-b|<\eta$.
Thus with this $\delta$ we have that $|x-a|<\delta$ implies first $|f(x)-b|<\eta$ and then $|g(f(x))-c|<\epsilon$.
In other words,
$$\lim_{x\to a} g(f(x)) = c. $$